# Missing Lookup fields in Sharepoint Online Pnp

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

Basically, I have three lists: Users, Agencies, and Office. The Users list has a Agency lookup field to the Agencies list and an Office lookup field to the Office list. The lists in SharePoint displays all the fields.

When I use **Get-PnpField** to display fields in my list I all the fields, however, when I use **Get-PnpListItem.FieldValues** fields are missing. In my case it's lookup fields, that look up items in other SharePoint lists.  There is a lookup field "Dept" in my Users list that does work, but I can't seem to find, let alone manipulate, the Agency and Office lookup fields .

I've read there may be limits on the number of lookup fields in a SharePoint List, but it is working in sharepoint and I'd rather number delete anything until I know.

```
**$sd = Get-PnPList -Identity 'Directory'
$Items = Get-PnPListItem  -List $sd.title

Get-PnPField -List $sd.Title**

Title                      InternalName               Id
-----                      ------------               --
Title                      Title                      fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247
Staff                      Staff                      20c8bcd5-371e-4050-866a-3790bc34ed11
User                       User                       15e8758a-f21b-47d5-a693-077c4e299b22
Order                      Order0                     12ef08a6-adc7-4f73-adb8-79a87f39cef5
Phone                      Phone                      5c50bd17-babb-4295-8dfb-7dff60ea4212
OtherPhone                 OtherPhone                 2e84f778-d66e-4a68-9759-2cd290e450bc
Fax                        Fax                        1d597500-0376-4bab-b51a-fedb47210e7b
Primary                    Primary                    5354a36c-a7e0-426a-a2ef-6f99187679bb
Email                      Email                      23ea738b-444d-41d8-9440-35163f9cef3c
DisplayName                DisplayName                ea6293ce-f506-4e5d-9646-bc09449cccb5
Dept                       Dept                       072c559e-f7d2-4431-9694-c4bc5ac36f3d
Title                      LinkTitleNoMenu            bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d
Title                      LinkTitle                  82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31
Title                      LinkTitle2                 5f190d91-3dbc-4489-9878-3c092caf35b6
_Order                     Order                      ca4addac-796f-4b23-b093-d2a3f65c0774
CtName                     Dept_x003a_CtName          91692227-637b-483d-ab0a-205dc46c338c
DeptName                   Dept_x003a_DeptName        6276ec5a-3883-483a-a0ca-5c3c1116e02c
FaxNo                      Dept_x003a_FaxNo           77effaed-56e5-4b90-8604-cf3e150d4776
Mail                       Mail                       91c75fc5-b77f-435a-929d-cd43b42f8545
FirstName                  FirstName                  924a9ab5-11de-4f4a-8be8-25face191f9a
LastName                   LastName                   d3170352-903b-411b-88d1-86ffaa9eb13c
Rname                      Rname                      28194977-e009-4599-af7d-a5a2ad627153
Temp                       Temp                       cd0d968a-1875-42c9-91d9-16a152cd6e14
Username                   Username                   b8d6c2b5-1960-45a9-82fb-695fbc0d4326
FullName                   FullName                   8f204fcd-850b-4b0a-af5c-ea565341946a
WorkTitle                  WorkTitle                  461da2e8-8630-420c-b196-b305ea4ffd18
WorkEMail                  WorkEMail                  a1928f03-6a5d-48ed-84b1-d9323f2e176a
WorkPhone                  WorkPhone                  0b5749da-6560-4a79-a61c-c3bbdd78ea89
GivenName                  GivenName                  88c5af5d-d37b-4c52-bee0-c2e360208da2
SurName                    SurName                    11b91496-e268-4521-b16c-0251b8d81b13
Photo                      Photo                      15a33eb0-47d7-4f71-a402-73541e4c98f8
Account                    Account                    a4cb2a6e-19b5-439f-8fcb-4572a1fd0801
ListOrder                  ListOrder                  44ba03b4-ae94-4072-9a8c-43a2d5d8f273
Office                     Office                     0da809c3-fd0c-4986-b942-f1be304eefe3
Agency                     Agency                     d2d50ea1-7f38-4e65-9660-5a6866eed866
ID                         ID                         1d22ea11-1e32-424e-89ab-9fedbadb6ce1


**$items[2].FieldValues**

Key                       Value
---                       -----
Title                     Office Clerical Assistant (PT)
Staff                     Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue
User                      jsmith
Order0                    1
Phone                     111-111-1111
OtherPhone
Fax
Primary                   True
Email                     jsmith@nycourts.gov
Dept                      Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue
ContentTypeId             0x010015D03C0F56A8604C9C3963F2DEA75564
_ModerationComments
File_x0020_Type
ComplianceAssetId
Order                     12600
Dept_x003a_CtName         Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue
Dept_x003a_DeptName       Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue
Setiteml                  5
Dept_x003a_FaxNo          Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue
Mail                      jsmith@nycourts.gov
FirstName                 Jon
LastName                  Smith
Rname                     Smith, Jon
Temp                      A
Username
FullName                  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue
WorkTitle                 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue
WorkEMail                 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue
WorkPhone                 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue
GivenName                 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue
SurName                   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue
Photo                     Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue
ListOrder                 016000020000100
ID                        126
```

Thanks for any guidance you may offer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce this issue in my environment. I think the problem is with the number of the following types of columns in a list goes over to 12: **people**, **lookup**, and **managed metadata**, which is the number mentioned that might cause [list view thresholds error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59).

When we use the command `Get-PnPListItem.FieldValues`, it should return all columns including the hidden ones which are also one of these types. So some of the columns (in your scenario *Agency* and *Office*) are left out.

You can run the script in another list with fewer person or group/lookup columns and see the result. Reduce the number of these types of columns if possible.